# Find determinant and inverse matrix, when coefficients are modulo 26 in Python

Tags: python, matrix, determinants

I try to encode Hill cipher in Python, but i have some problems.

I consider matrices that their coefficients are integers modulo 26

> How to make a program that calculates the determinant of that matrix?

And second question:

> How to find inversion of that matrix ?(if exists)

Regards

Comment: Please show some code of what you have tried.

Comment: I assume you have some speed requirements. What are they? Otherwise, you can just use: `numpy.linalg.det` and `numpy.linalg.pinv`.

Comment: But is this going to work for integers modulo 26?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Sagemath (run your code in Sage or import Sage into Python), you can use:

```
M = Matrix(Zmod(26), your_numpy_matrix)
determinant = M.det()
inverse = M.inverse()
```

Theoretically, you can compute the whole determinant and then apply modulo, but this will lead to problems.

I tried `sympy`, but did not manager a working solution for larger dimension.

```
M = sympy.Matrix(your_numpy_matrix)
determinant = M.det() % 26 #huge intermediate results/crashes
inverse = M.inv_mod(26)
```

`numpy` will not work, as you will encounter numerical problems.

PS: I am aware, the question is old, but I wanted to document possible solutions.